# Writing integers into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have some code:

```
file = open("tester.log","w")

file.write(int(5))
file.write(int(8))
```

I am trying to write integer values into the file but I keep getting this error:

```
write() argument must be str, not int
```

Is there any way to fix this while keeping the code simple.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `write` wants a string. -> `file.write('5')`.

Comment: How can I write integers so that I could retrieve the data and add it up or something.

Comment: In the same way.

Comment: @J.Doe You write in the text file using file.write(str(5)) and you can calculate it like this: For a better example I am gonna put the integer as a string into a variable. `test = "8"` . If I wannt add it with another integer I simply do `print(int(test)+5)` and it will work fine. So you can write the numbers as a string in the file and use it later as a integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `file.write(str(5))` to write an int to a file.